# Дискорд периодически останавливает выполнение кода бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Дело следующее: есть бот, который каждые 3 секунды редактирует конкретное (своё) сообщение, обновляя данные в нём. Но вот незадача - он периодически останавливается (а именно перестаёт редактировать сообщение, но не уходит в оффлайн). В консоли, в основном 2 ошибки: Connection reset by peer и следующая: https://ibb.co/3zyZGZ2.
Если с первой хоть что-то мне понятно (кроме того, как её пофиксить), то причины возникновения второй мне не известны.
Код бота:

````
import discord, asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import datetime

import config

filenamewrite = config.fnw
filenamewrite2 = config.fnw2
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'a!')

@tasks.loop(seconds = config.SEC)
async def AutoListUpload():
    with open(filenamewrite, 'rb') as f:
        cnt = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    with open(filenamewrite2, 'rb') as f:
        cnt2 = f.read().decode('utf-8')
    channel = bot.get_channel(config.CHANNEL)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(config.MESSAGE)
    d = datetime.datetime.today()
    almsg = '```' + 'Morrowind Online' + '\n' + 'Онлайн состоянием на ' + str(d.day) + '.' + str(d.month) + '.' + str(d.year) + ' ' + str(d.hour) + ':' + str(d.minute) + '\n' + '\n' + cnt + '```'
    await message.edit(content = almsg)
    await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Activity(name = f'Нирне, ' + cnt2 + ' игроками.', type = discord.ActivityType.playing))
    
@AutoListUpload.before_loop
async def before_ALU():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    if not AutoListUpload.is_running():
        AutoListUpload.start()

bot.run(config.TOKEN)
````

Имею подозрение что, возможно, дискорд стопорит бота через слишком частое редактирование сообщения, но думаю что в таком случае он падал бы через час после запуска, в реальности же - периодичность остановок примерно раз в день. Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

прерывание работы вашего бота происходит по причине того что из-за частого редактирования сообщения сервера discord обрывают соединение и возобновляют через время(это сделано что бы не перегружать сервера)
возможные пути решения:
увеличение интервала между действиями и установка ограничения на количество операций